# Arcpy.ValidateFieldName does not validate field name?

Tags: python, validation, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I am working on a Python script using Arcpy. It creates a shape file, and then adds fields to it with names coming from user input. From the string the user has entered I need to produce a valid field name. I thought [`arcpy.ValidateFieldName()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000087000000) would accomplish this. However, I am having problems. Consider the code below:

```
#Create a new shapefile.
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\path\to\file", "shape.shp")

#Validate the fieldname.
name = arcpy.ValidateFieldName("0FIELD", "shape")

#Add the field
arcpy.AddField_management("shape", name, "TEXT")
```

Even though the field name has been validated, it throws an error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\script.py", line 8, in   
>    arcpy.AddField_management("shape", name, "TEXT")
>     File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3200, in AddField
>       raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000310: The Field name must not start with a number

The function corrects other unallowed character (such as replacing spaces with underscores, and capping the string at 10 characters), but it misses to do something about the first character being a number even though that is not allowed in shape file field names.

Is this a bug, or am I using `arcpy.ValidateFieldName()` wrongly? Is there some other function I should use? Or will I have to write one myself? What should that one look like?

**EDIT 1:** Replacing the second argument to `ValidateFieldName` with the full path and filename of the shape file does not help.

**EDIT 2:** When adding a field called `0FIELD` from ArcCatalog it works fine. So rather than this being a problem with the validation, it seems that `AddField_management` disallows field names starting with a number, even though it shouldn't.

Comment: I have a somewhat related question about `ValidateFieldName` on GIS Stack Exchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157090/problem-with-arcpy-validatefieldname-and-unicode-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in contact with ESRI support, and according to them it is an issue with ArcMap 10.2 that is fixed in 10.3. Have not been able to verify that, however.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the second parameter of arcpy.ValidateFieldName must be a path to a workspace.

For example:

```
name = arcpy.ValidateFieldName("0FIELD", r"C:\your_workspace.gdb")
```

This is to allow the function to generate a valid field name based on the type of workspace you are using.

Good luck,

Tom

Comment: I tried using `r"C:\path\to\file\filename.shp"` as the second parameter, and it makes no difference.

Comment: Hi Anders, please review the difference between a shapefile and a workspace. ESRI has online documentation on this, so a Google search should serve you well.